# javascript Function calling only in EditMode

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

am new to Javascript i have a MVC View(AddUser.cshtml) and the same will be called on edit action also, this AddUser.cshtml has JS function which gets called in  $(document).ready(function () {
BindEditData();
}. am trying to call it only on edit mode but somehow unsuccessful in doing so. it's getting in ADD action also. Please see my code, Please suggest ....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
    var data = {
        GlobalVar: [
        ]}



    if ($("#UserID").val()>0) {

        SetAddressDataInEditMode();
    } 

   function SetAddressDataInEditMode()
        {
                var myArray = [];

                 @foreach(var d in Model.MyModel)
                 {
                 @:InsertAddressData("@d.AddressID", "@d.AddressLabel", "@d.Line1", "@d.Line2", "@d.CountryID", "@d.CountryStateID", "@d.StateCityID", "@d.Zip", "@d.Status");
                  }
            function InsertAddressData
                (SAddressID, SAddressLabel, SLine1, SLine2, SCountryID,
                SCountryStateID, SStateCityID, SZip, SStatus)
            {

                data.GlobalVar.push({
                    AddressID: SAddressID,
                    AddressLabel: SAddressLabel,
                    Line1: SLine1,
                    Line2: SLine2,
                    CountryID: SCountryID,
                    CountryStateID: SCountryStateID,
                    StateCityID: SStateCityID,
                    Zip: SZip,
                    Status: SStatus
                });
            }

            //Call Display address
            DisplayAddressDetails();

        }
```

Comment: There is not `BindEditData` in the js code you posted. Is the model's unique identifier property `UserID` with proper casing?

Comment: Yes, UserID is unique identifier, am not using BindEditData fucntion here, am directly calling the above func in Doc.ready() method.

Comment: The code you have posted should work fine. You're doing something else wrong. Add a breakpoint at `if ($("#UserID").val()>0)` line in the browser and debug. Or add a `console.log($("#UserID").val())` before that line, and check the value in console.